# How do I set the height of tableHeaderView (UITableView) with autolayout?

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout, uitableview

I'm been smashing my head against the wall with this for last 3 or 4 hours and I can't seem to figure it out. I have a UIViewController with a full screen UITableView inside of it (there's some other stuff on the screen, which is why I can't use a UITableViewController) and I want to get my tableHeaderView to resize with autolayout. Needless to say, it's not cooperating.

See screenshot below.

[image]

Because the overviewLabel (e.g. the "List overview information here." text) has dynamic content, I'm using autolayout to resize it and it's superview. I've got everything resizing nicely, except for the tableHeaderView, which is right below Paralax Table View in the hiearchy.

The only way I've found to resize that header view is programatically, with the following code:

```
CGRect headerFrame = self.headerView.frame;
headerFrame.size.height = headerFrameHeight;
self.headerView.frame = headerFrame;
[self.listTableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
```

In this case, headerFrameHeight is a manual calculation of the tableViewHeader height as follows *(innerHeaderView is the white area, or the second "View", headerView is tableHeaderView)*:

```
CGFloat startingY = self.innerHeaderView.frame.origin.y + self.overviewLabel.frame.origin.y;
CGRect overviewSize = [self.overviewLabel.text
                       boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(290.f, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                       options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: self.overviewLabel.font}
                       context:nil];
CGFloat overviewHeight = overviewSize.size.height;
CGFloat overviewPadding = ([self.overviewLabel.text length] > 0) ? 10 : 0; // If there's no overviewText, eliminate the padding in the overall height.
CGFloat headerFrameHeight = ceilf(startingY + overviewHeight + overviewPadding + 21.f + 10.f);
```

The manual calculation works, but it's clunky and prone to error if things change in the future. What I want to be able to do is have the tableHeaderView auto-resize based on the provided constraints, like you can anywhere else. But for the life of me, I can't figure it out.

There's several posts on SO about this, but none are clear and ended up confusing me more. Here's a few:

- [Auto layout on UITableViewHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637376/auto-layout-on-uitableviewheader)
- [Auto Layout for tableHeaderView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281691/auto-layout-for-tableheaderview)
- [Is it possible to use AutoLayout with UITableView's tableHeaderView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16471846/is-it-possible-to-use-autolayout-with-uitableviews-tableheaderview)
- [table header view height is wrong when using auto layout, IB, and font sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005446/table-header-view-height-is-wrong-when-using-auto-layout-ib-and-font-sizes)

It doesn't really make sense to change the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property to NO, since that just causes errors for me and doesn't make sense conceptually anyway.

Any help would really be appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to TomSwift's suggestion, I was able to figure it out. Instead of manually calculating the height of the overview, I can have it calculated for me as follows and then re-set the tableHeaderView as before.

```
[self.headerView setNeedsLayout];
[self.headerView layoutIfNeeded];
CGFloat height = [self.innerHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height + self.innerHeaderView.frame.origin.y; // adding the origin because innerHeaderView starts partway down headerView.

CGRect headerFrame = self.headerView.frame;
headerFrame.size.height = height;
self.headerView.frame = headerFrame;
[self.listTableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];
```

**Edit 2:** As others have noted, the solution posted in Edit 1 doesn't seem to work in viewDidLoad. It does, however, seem to work in viewWillLayoutSubviews. Example code below:

```
// Note 1: The variable names below don't match the variables above - this is intended to be a simplified "final" answer.
// Note 2: _headerView was previously assigned to tableViewHeader (in loadView in my case since I now do everything programatically).
// Note 3: autoLayout code can be setup programatically in updateViewConstraints.
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    [_headerWrapper setNeedsLayout];
    [_headerWrapper layoutIfNeeded];
    CGFloat height = [_headerWrapper systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    CGRect headerFrame = _headerWrapper.frame;
    headerFrame.size.height = height;
    _headerWrapper.frame = headerFrame;
    _tableView.tableHeaderView = _headerWrapper;
}
```

Comment: `setTableHeaderView` does not work on Xcode6. The problem is that cells are overlapped by the tableHeaderView. However, it works on Xcode5

Comment: @DawnSong do know a solution for Xcode6 so that I can update the answer?

Comment: After a lot of trial, I use UITableViewCell instead of tableHeaderView, and it works.

Comment: I smashed my head too!

Comment: The true complete autolayout solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38386985/2066428)

Comment: Edit 2 eventually worked for me but be careful: I was trying to do this in a subclass of UITableViewController. Since the vc's root view is the table view changing the header height in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` causes an infinite loop. Simple workaround was to use just a vanilla UIViewController and add the table view as a subview of its view.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubviews() works fine for me

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34661793/setting-tableheaderview-height-dynamically?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to use the `UIView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:` method to obtain the minimum bounding size of your header view.

I provide further discussion on using this API in this Q/A:

[How to resize superview to fit all subviews with autolayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118021/how-to-resize-superview-to-fit-all-subviews-with-autolayout/18155803#18155803)

Comment: It's coming back with height = 0, although I'm not 100% sure I've configured it right since this isn't a UITableViewCell, so there isn't the contentView to call "systemLayoutSizeFittingSize" on.

What I tried:
[self.headerView setNeedsLayout];
[self.headerView layoutIfNeeded];
CGFloat height = [self.headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

CGRect headerFrame = self.headerView.frame;
headerFrame.size.height = height;
self.headerView.frame = headerFrame;
[self.listTableView setTableHeaderView:self.headerView];

I also confirmed that preferredMax... is valid.

Comment: Aha! Figured it out, I needed to do [self.innerHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize...] instead of self.headerView as that's what has the actual dynamic content. Thanks a ton!

Comment: It works but in my app there is a small height discrepancy. Probably because my labels are using an attributed text and Dynamic Type.

Answer (score 25):

I've found an elegant way to way to use auto layout to resize table headers, with and without animation.

Simply add this to your View Controller.

```
func sizeHeaderToFit(tableView: UITableView) {
    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var frame = headerView.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        headerView.frame = frame
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        headerView.setNeedsLayout()
        headerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

To resize according to a dynamically changing label:

```
@IBAction func addMoreText(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.label.text = self.label.text! + "\nThis header can dynamically resize according to its contents."
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // viewDidLayoutSubviews is called when labels change.
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    sizeHeaderToFit(tableView)
}
```

To animate a resize according to a changes in a constraint:

```
@IBOutlet weak var makeThisTallerHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func makeThisTaller(sender: AnyObject) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.makeThisTallerHeight.constant += 20
        self.sizeHeaderToFit(self.tableView)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

See the AutoResizingHeader project to see this in action.
https://github.com/p-sun/Swift2-iOS9-UI

[image: AutoResizingHeader]

Comment: Hey p-sun. Thanks for great example. Seems I have issue with tableViewHeader. I tried to have the same constraints like in your example, but not working. How exactly I should add constraints to label which i want to increase height ?  Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Make sure you hook the label you want to make taller to `@IBOutlet makeThisTaller` and `@IBAction fun makeThisTaller` like in the example. Also, constrain all sides of your label to the tableViewHeader (e.g. top, bottom, left, and right).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally solved by adding this line:
`lblFeedDescription.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = lblFeedDescription.bounds.width`
where label is that one which I want to increase size.  Thanks !

Comment: Thanks! If you're doing this inside a View instead of a ViewController, then instead of overriding viewDidLayoutSubviews, you can override layoutSubviews

Answer (score 23):

I really battled with this one and plonking the setup into viewDidLoad didn't work for me since the frame is not set in viewDidLoad, I also ended up with tons of messy warnings where the encapsulated auto layout height of the header was being reduced to 0. I only noticed the issue on iPad when presenting a tableView in a Form presentation.

What solved the issue for me was setting the tableViewHeader in viewWillLayoutSubviews rather than in viewDidLoad.

```
func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        if tableView.tableViewHeaderView == nil {
            let header: MyHeaderView = MyHeaderView.createHeaderView()
            header.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            header.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
            header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.bounds), CGFloat.max)
            var newFrame = header.frame
            header.setNeedsLayout()
            header.layoutIfNeeded()
            let newSize = header.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
            newFrame.size.height = newSize.height
            header.frame = newFrame
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header
        }
    }
```

Comment: for updated solution with minimal code  try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63594053/3933302

Answer (score 5):

This solution resizes the tableHeaderView and avoids infinite loop in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method I was having with some of the other answers here:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame

        // comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```

See also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689293/1245231

Comment: I am using this method too. Think it’s the best because there is no fiddling with constraints. It’s also very compact.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution using systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: works if the header view is just updated once on each view appearance. In my case, the header view updated multiple times to reflect status changes. But systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: always reported the same size. That is, the size corresponding to the first update.

To get systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: to return the correct size after each update I had to first remove the table header view before updating it and re-adding it:

```
self.listTableView.tableHeaderView = nil;
[self.headerView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on ios10 and Xcode 8

```
func layoutTableHeaderView() {

    guard let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView else { return }
    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let headerWidth = headerView.bounds.size.width;
    let temporaryWidthConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("[headerView(width)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)), metrics: ["width": headerWidth], views: ["headerView": headerView])

    headerView.addConstraints(temporaryWidthConstraints)

    headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let headerSize = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
    let height = headerSize.height
    var frame = headerView.frame

    frame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = frame

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

    headerView.removeConstraints(temporaryWidthConstraints)
    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**It works for both header view and footer just replace the header with footer**

```
func sizeHeaderToFit() {
    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {

        headerView.setNeedsLayout()
        headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var frame = headerView.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        headerView.frame = frame

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 12 and above, the following steps will ensure autolayout works properly in both your table and the header.

1. Create your tableView first, then the header.
2. At the end of your header creation code, call:

> ```
> [headerV setNeedsLayout];
> [headerV layoutIfNeeded];
> ```

3. Upon orientation change, mark the header for layout again and reload the table, this needs to happen slightly after the orientation change is reported:

> ```
> dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 *NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>
>   [tableV.tableHeaderView setNeedsLayout];
>   [tableV.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
>   [tableV reloadData];});
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `viewDidLayoutSubviews` worked better. `viewWillLayoutSubviews` causes white lines of a `tableView` to appear. Also I added checking if my `headerView` object already exists.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if ( ! self.userHeaderView ) {
        // Setup HeaderView
        self.userHeaderView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SSUserHeaderView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.userHeaderView setNeedsLayout];
        [self.userHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
        CGFloat height = [self.userHeaderView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
        CGRect headerFrame = self.userHeaderView.frame;
        headerFrame.size.height = height;
        self.userHeaderView.frame = headerFrame;
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.userHeaderView;

        // Update HeaderView with data
        [self.userHeaderView updateWithProfileData];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible to use generic AutoLayout-based `UIView` with any AL inner subview structure as a `tableHeaderView`.

The only thing one needs is to set a simple `tableFooterView` before!

Let `self.headerView` is some constraint-based `UIView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    ........................

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

    [self.headerView layoutIfNeeded]; // to set initial size

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;

    [self.tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.headerView.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.headerView.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.headerView.topAnchor].active = YES;

    // and the key constraint
    [self.tableFooterView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.headerView.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
}
```

If `self.headerView` changes height under UI rotation one have to implement

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition: ^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        // needed to resize header height
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
    } completion: NULL];
}
```

One can use *ObjC* category for this purpose

```
@interface UITableView (AMHeaderView)
- (void)am_insertHeaderView:(UIView *)headerView;
@end

@implementation UITableView (AMHeaderView)

- (void)am_insertHeaderView:(UIView *)headerView {

    NSAssert(self.tableFooterView, @"Need to define tableFooterView first!");

    [headerView layoutIfNeeded];

    self.tableHeaderView = headerView;

    [self.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.topAnchor].active = YES;

    [self.tableFooterView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:headerView.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
}
@end
```

And also *Swift* extension

```
extension UITableView {

    func am_insertHeaderView2(_ headerView: UIView) {

        assert(tableFooterView != nil, "Need to define tableFooterView first!")

        headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

        tableHeaderView = headerView

        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

        tableFooterView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works perfectly for me:

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/11/swift-extending-uitableviewcontroller/

It extends the UITableViewController. But if you are just using a UITableView, it will still work, just extend the UITableView instead of the UITableViewController.
Call the methods `sizeHeaderToFit()` or `sizeFooterToFit()` whenever there is an event that changes the `tableViewHeader` height.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689293/3933302)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    if let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView {

        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
        var headerFrame = headerView.frame
        
        //Comparison necessary to avoid infinite loop
        if height != headerFrame.size.height {
            headerFrame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = headerFrame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
}
```