# Scrolling ViewController Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

What I have in the view controller view are :

1. An image of fixed height
2. Few labels
3. Table view with n rows.

Once rendered I want everything here to be inside the scroll the view so the user can scroll the entire screen as needed. Note that the `scrollView` needs to expand to the entire size of the `tableView` to show its full contents. I have tried different ways of doing this but unable to do it. I would appreciate any pointers or code segment to get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially two ways to do so.

#### tableHeaderView

The first way involves the `tableHeaderView` property of the `UITableView` instance you have. You can simply add the `UITableView` with the constraints/frame/autoresizingMask that allows you to put it full-screen. Done that, you simply do (i.e. in your `viewDidLoad`):

```c
UIView *headerView = [UIView new];

// Here I am supposing that you have a 200pt high view and a `self.tableView` UITableView
headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 200.0);

UIImageView *fixedImageView = [UIImageView new];
// configure your imageView..
[headerView addSubview:fixedImageView];

// configure labels as you want and add them to headerView as subviews

// Now set `UITableView` headerView
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

If you want to use AutoLayout for your tableHeaderView, I suggest you to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982558/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-tableheaderview-uitableview-with-autolayout)

#### Dynamic scrollView

Another way to do this is to to create an `UIScrollView`, put everything inside, and let it scroll. The downside of this method is that if you are using floating section headers for your `UITableView`, they will not float due to the fact that the `tableView` is going to stay *fixed*, while the parent `scrollView` is going to scroll.

On the other side, this approach is more AutoLayout friendly due to the fact you can use constraints easily.

To do so, you start adding an `UIScrollView` to your view, and placing all your other views inside it.
Be sure to add a **Vertical Spacing** constraint between the first view inside your `scrollView` (I suppose the `UIImageView`) and the `scrollView` top, and between the last view (I suppose the `UITableView`) and the `scrollView` bottom, to avoid an ambiguous content size.

You should have something like that (I omitted the labels for the sake of brevity):

[image: UITableView Autolayout inside scrollView]

> Note that every view is inside a parent `UIScrollView`

After that, add an **Height** constraint to the `tableView`, and add an `IBOutlet` to your view controller subclass, i.e. like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableViewHeightConstraint;
```

Now you only need to configure this constraint to reflect the `tableView` natural height, given by its rows, etc. To do so, you simply calculate the height in this way:

```
// Resize TableView
CGFloat height = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = height;
```

Now the tableView will resize, and due to its constraints it will adapt the parent `scrollView` contentSize.

Just be sure to refresh this height constraint anytime you reload the `UITableView` dataSource.