# -systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: returning incorrect height for tableHeaderView under iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

There are numerous threads about correctly sizing a tableHeaderView with auto-layout ([one such thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982558/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-tableheaderview-uitableview-with-autolayout)) but they tend to pre-date iOS 8.

I have a situation with numerous table views, all with headers, that size correctly under iOS 7 but incorrectly under iOS 8 using the code that most of the aforementioned threads champion. In the controllers for the tables, I have the following method:

```
- (void)rejiggerTableHeaderView
{
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;

    UIView *header = self.headerView;

    [header setNeedsLayout];
    [header layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    CGRect headerFrame = header.frame;
    headerFrame.size.height = height;

    header.frame = headerFrame;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
}
```

With a multi-line label under iOS 7, this correctly sizes the table view's header like so:

[image]

But the same code run under iOS 8 produces the following:

[image]

What's the trick to getting -systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: to return the correct size under iOS 8? [Here's a sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyi4if92x4zj1c4/IncorrectHeight.zip?dl=0) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Changing your headerview function to the following works for me:

```c
- (void)rejiggerTableHeaderView
{
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil;

    UIView *header = self.headerView;
    CGRect frame = header.frame;
    frame.size.width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;
    header.frame = frame;

    [header setNeedsLayout];
    [header layoutIfNeeded];

    CGFloat height = [header systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    CGRect headerFrame = header.frame;
    headerFrame.size.height = height;

    header.frame = headerFrame;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header;
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, that does fix it. Thank you very much. For what it's worth, iOS 8.1 fixed things so it behaved as it did in 7.1 (the screenshot above is from 8.0.2). But upon doing additional poking in my sample project, I realized both screenshots above are incorrect anyway. The height of the view was getting set to properly enclose the string if rotated into landscape mode, so your fix of explicitly stating what the real width of the view is fixes it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I have two labels inside the header, one of them is not resized correctly. Only three lines are shown.

Comment: I found that the culprit was a missing constraint: it is critical to have a strut from the `UILabel` in all 4 directions against the superview. A single missing constraint will prevent `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize` from working properly.

Comment: This answer is outdated and doesn't handle Size classes properly. I have posted an updated answer, for anyone looking now.

Answer (score 17):

Problem can be in non-set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`.
If you will set it to correct UILabel width, it will determine constraints correctly.

You can go through all `UILabel` in header and set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` to label width.

Swift 3 example:

```
extension UITableView {
    public func relayoutTableHeaderView() {
        if let tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView {
            let labels = tableHeaderView.findViewsOfClass(viewClass: UILabel.self)
            for label in labels {
                label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.width
            }
            tableHeaderView.setNeedsLayout()
            tableHeaderView.layoutIfNeeded()
            tableHeaderView.frame.height = tableHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
            self.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
        }
    }

    public func findViewsOfClass<T:UIView>(viewClass: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var views: [T] = []
        for subview in subviews {
            if subview is T {
                views.append(subview as! T)
            }
            views.append(contentsOf: subview.findViewsOfClass(viewClass: T.self))
        }
        return views
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Also you can have problem with incorrect height calculation if you have subview with aspect ratio constraint and at the same time proportional to superview width constraint

Answer (score 8):

Since this question is a year and a half old, here is a updated and complete version, in Swift. Some of the code from the accepted answer is wrong or outdated.

```
func fixHeaderHeight() {
    // Set your label text if needed
    // ...
    //

    guard let header = tableView.tableHeaderView else {
        return
    }    
    let height = header.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    header.frame.height = height            
    tableView.tableHeaderView = header
}
```

Somewhere else in your code, you'll need to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of the label(s) in the header. This should be equal to the tableView (or screen width) minus any padding. The `didSet` method of your label outlet is a good place:

```
@IBOutlet weak var headerMessageLabel: UILabel! {
        didSet {
            headerMessageLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - headerMessageLabelPadding
        }
    }
```

**Note:** If the accepted answer worked for you, you aren't using size classes properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the header just contains a single label then I use a `UILabel` extension to find a multiline label height given a width:

```
public extension UILabel {
    public class func size(withText text: String, forWidth width: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        let measurementLabel = UILabel()
        measurementLabel.text = text
        measurementLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        measurementLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        measurementLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        measurementLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
        let size = measurementLabel.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
        return size
    }
}
```

**Note**: the above is in Swift 3 syntax.

With the `size` calculated above you can return the correct height in the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution for this problem in Swift 3 is using this class instead of standard UILabel:

```
class UILabelPreferedWidth : UILabel {
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if (bounds.size.width != oldValue.size.width) {
                self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
            }
        }
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        if(preferredMaxLayoutWidth != bounds.size.width) {
            preferredMaxLayoutWidth = bounds.size.width
        }
        super.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you didn't disable those two on your Cell class:

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a same problem.
This works well for me on iOS 8.4.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self.myLabel sizeToFit];
    [self.tableView.tableHeaderView layoutIfNeeded];
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```