# tableHeaderView height by it's content won't work as it should

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I'm trying to set `tableHeaderView` height by the `UILabel` that I placed inside. But for some reason I have problems with it, the height is smaller than the label's content and for sometimes the label won't show the full text.

**This is how it looks:**

[image]

**This is how it should look:**

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
extension UITableView {
    public func relayoutTableHeaderView() {
        if let tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView {
            let labels = tableHeaderView.findViewsOfClass(viewClass: UILabel.self)
            for label in labels {
                label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.width
            }
            tableHeaderView.setNeedsLayout()
            tableHeaderView.layoutIfNeeded()
            tableHeaderView.frame.size.height = tableHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
            self.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
            print(tableHeaderView.frame)
        }
    }
}

extension UIView {
    public func findViewsOfClass<T:UIView>(viewClass: T.Type) -> [T] {
        var views: [T] = []
        for subview in subviews {
            if subview is T {
                views.append(subview as! T)
            }
            views.append(contentsOf: subview.findViewsOfClass(viewClass: T.self))
        }
        return views
    }
}
```

The resource of this piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30925866/1138498).

Answer (score 0):

You are not using Number of lines to zero

```
    extension UITableView {
    public func relayoutTableHeaderView() {
        if let tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView {
            let labels = tableHeaderView.findViewsOfClass(viewClass: UILabel.self)
            for label in labels {
                label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.width
                label.numberOfLines = 0
            }
            tableHeaderView.setNeedsLayout()
            tableHeaderView.layoutIfNeeded()
            tableHeaderView.frame.size.height = tableHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height
            self.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
            print(tableHeaderView.frame)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still I have some label which are not in the correct height even when numberOfLines is set to 0... https://ibb.co/0X5Y7Ln

Comment: have you used auto layouts are not ?