# Set UITableView header view height depends on its childviews

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a headerview in my UITableView but I can't find a solution to make it dynamically height. In my headerview I have a UITextView which height depends on its content.

What I have tried so far.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    sizeHeaderToFit()
}


func sizeHeaderToFit() {

    let headerView = mTabView.tableHeaderView!

    mTxtViewDescription.sizeToFit()
    mConDescriptionHeight.constant = mTxtViewDescription.frame.height

    print(mContainerView.frame.maxY)

    headerView.frame.size.height += mTxtViewDescription.frame.height


}
```

The green area is my headerview

[image]

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: The headerview should only go down to the bottom of phonenumber view (UIView) - Sorry I didn't mention that @NRitH

Comment: might be interesting http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the height of the frame of a UITableView header that's already been set won't recalculate the height, meaning you can't just change the height of a tableHeaderView as its layout is managed by the tableView.  You need to set the tableHeaderView again, setting the property triggers the new calculation. 
There are a number of questions going into detail about this, several linked from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982558/how-do-i-set-the-height-of-tableheaderview-uitableview-with-autolayout).