# tableview section header is not sticky in multi sectional tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have implemented a tableview (4 sectional) in IOS. Problem is that
I have just added a section header in first section.Other sections don't have a header.First section does not have row (number of rows is 0).other sections have multiple rows.When I scroll , first section's header is not sticky.it is scrolling and out of screen.My table view style is plain.How can I want to make first section's header is always sticky.Code is below.Unfortunatelly tableview is so complicated and I don't want to make it only one section so that I have implemented it multi sectional.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        return tabHeaderView.contentView
    }
    else {
        return UIView()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
      return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    else {
        return 0 //just first section have a header (tabview)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if dataReady {
        totalSectionCount = getSectionCount()
        return totalSectionCount
    }
    else {
        return 1 //permanent because of tabview
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if !dataReady || ApplicationContext.instance.userAuthenticationStatus.value == .semiSecure{
        return 1//for shimmer cell and semisecure view
    }
    else {
        return getNumberOfRows(sectionNumber: section)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if ApplicationContext.instance.userAuthenticationStatus.value == .semiSecure {
        semisecureViewCell = EarningsSemisecureViewCell()
        setSemisecureViewTextInfo(cell: semisecureViewCell)
        semisecureViewCell.delegate = self
        semisecureViewCell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return semisecureViewCell
    }
    else if !dataReady {
        return getShimmerCell()
    }
    else {
        if indexPath.row == 0 && !(selectedTabIndex == .BRANDPOINT && indexPath.section == 1){//marka puan listesinde header cell olmayacak
            return getSectionHeaderViewCell(tableView: tableView,sectionNumber: indexPath.section)
        }
        else {
            let cell = getTableViewCell(tableView: tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dit it.Fisrt section ehader must be sticky.

Comment: where is the code of getSectionCount() method?

Comment: sorry, I forgot it .there is no problem about section count but I have changed  code to only one section and I managed all cells in a section.it is done.thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Each section header will stick to the top until that section has some rows to display. Once you scroll all the rows for the section up. section header will be replaced by the next section header.

Here you can use one of the two solutions.

1. Instead of table view section header. Put your view on top of UITableView.
2. You can use only one section and combine all the rows in it.

Comment: I have also a tableheaderview.I think you are right about it.I must combine all in one section.Thank you so much :)

Comment: Solution 1 is nice. :)  Put your view on top of tableView, or add the view to the same parent view of tableView.

Answer (score 1):

From how you are describing your setup, I tend to believe that what you are looking for is the `tableHeaderView` of the `tableView`, not the section header.

See either [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20982558/2912282), or [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview) for more info.

If that does not meet your requirements, you might wanna consider a custom view on top of the `tableView`, as is described [here](https://medium.com/@aunnnn/table-header-view-with-autolayout-13de4cfc4343).

Answer (score 0):

If the first section must always be sticky when any section is displaying, I will consider to put a custom view on top of tableView. Use autoLayout or UIStackView to let it work as a table header view.

Comment: I have also a tableheaderview.I think I must combine all secitons in one